# Mouseup Function Prevents Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have corresponding buttons and divs where if one button is clicked, a menu is displayed and any other menu that may be open is hidden.

I am also hiding these menus if a user clicks elsewhere on the page, however the `mouseup` event I'm using prevents the menu from hiding when a user clicks the button element a second time.

```
$(document).on("click", ".some-btn", function(e) { //toggles the dropdown menu
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu');
    $(this).nextAll('dropdown-menu').first().toggle(); 
    $(".actions-dropdown-menu").not($this).hide(); 
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e){ //hides the menu if user clicks elsewhere
    var dropdown = $('.dropdown-menu');
    if(!dropdown.is(e.target) && dropdown.has(e.target).length === 0){
        dropdown.hide();
    }
});
```

Buttons/Menus:

```
<button class="some-btn"></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
<button class="some-btn"></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
```

I've tried taking out the condition to check if the dropdown isn't the `target` but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I was checking for the wrong element on mouseup. Should have been checking for the button not the menu. This now works correctly:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){ //hides the menu if user clicks elsewhere
    var button = $('.some-btn');
    if(!button .is(e.target) && button.has(e.target).length === 0){
        $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    }
});
```